# Virus found at [win32:rootkit-gen] at c/program files/common file/odbc/comp.exe Should i remove?

Tags: virus

my antivirus found a virus named  "win32:rootkit-gen" at this location   c/program files/common file/odbc/comp.exe

Should i remove that virus or tell my antivirus to ignore it.Is it an imp windows file?has the virus successfully fooled the antivirus by prompting to delete an important file?plz help

Answer (score 1):

While it is always possible to have a *false positive*, it would be better if you took your AV's advice and got rid of the file immediately. Then update and run a complete scan of your drive(s). You can also download an AV rescue disc (preferably on another PC), burn it, boot from it and scan your system. Here are instructions for [Avira](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38889/how-to-use-the-avira-rescue-cd-to-clean-your-infected-pc/), [BitDefender](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/36677/how-to-use-the-bitdefender-rescue-cd-to-clean-your-infected-pc/) and [Kaspersky](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/36403/how-to-use-the-kaspersky-rescue-disk-to-clean-your-infected-pc/).

Ensure you have a Windows setup disc on hand, to repair the installation if required (i.e. if the system fails to boot after cleaning and restarting).

If you feel your system has been compromised and are unsure whether every trace of the infection was cleaned, the only option left is a complete nuke and reinstall of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the file to a flash drive, deleting it on the computer, and if you have problems, copy it back. Or create a System Restore point, then delete the file. Then if the computer doesn't work, just restore from that restore point.

Comment: Viruses can infect system restores, so make sure to run a scan after the restore if you go with this answer, OP.